# Set Current Place in Place Autocomplete Fragment

Tags: android, autocomplete

I want to set the current place into the place autocomplete fragment when the activity is created.

I am able to Load Google Maps API and I have successfully implemented Place Autocomplete Fragment in my application. But, I want place autocomplete fragment to set the current place as default string in place autocomplete fragment. Just like Uber does. When we open Uber and click on the edit text saying "Where to?" it ask us to enter or search for destination location and it automatically set the location to the current place. My code is given below:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceDetectionApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final int REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.aubergine_maps_style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("MapsActivityRaw", "Can't find style.", e);
    }

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney)); */
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                }, REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
        }
    }

    Location location = getLastKnownLocation();

    if (location != null)
    {
        this.mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        this.mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        double latitude = 0;
        double longitude = 0;
        if (!tracker.canGetLocation()) {
            tracker.showSettingsAlert();
        } else {
            latitude = tracker.getLatitude();
            longitude = tracker.getLongitude();
        }

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Is Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setText("");

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            System.out.println("Place Name: " + place.getName());
            System.out.println("Place ID: " + place.getId());
            System.out.println("Place Address: " + place.getAddress());
            System.out.println("Place LatLng: " + place.getLatLng());
            String latLng = place.getLatLng().toString();
            latLng = latLng.replace("lat/lng: (", "");
            latLng = latLng.replace(")","");
            String[] latLngArray = latLng.split(",");
            System.out.println("Latitude Only: " + latLngArray[0]);
            System.out.println("Longitude Only: " + latLngArray[1]);

            mMap.clear();

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latLngArray[0]), Double.parseDouble(latLngArray[1])))
                    .title(place.getName().toString())
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

}

private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);;
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    }, REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
                }
            }
        }
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        System.out.println("last known location, provider: %s, location: %s");

        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null
                || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            System.out.println("found best last known location: %s");
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    if (bestLocation == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? if yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm li'l bit late to answer this question. I found the most prominent solution below. maybe it will help someone. Direct solution is `setText` method of `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` API. For Detailed answer please go through below answer.

1. Load the Google Map
2. Init the PlaceAutocompleteFragment
3. getCurrentLocation inside onMapReady Method
4. set current location Marker
5. Now, Simply set the name of PlaceAutocompleteFragment by calling its setText Method. (e.g. `sourcePlace.setText("Current Location");`)

Note: This is the simplest method I have found for my requirements. Try it, if it suits your requirement also.

Answer (score 0):

Despite it is already 3 years later, I decided to answer in case there is someone needs it. The same problem I faced and had to open Places Autocomplete PROGRAMATICALLY.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity Since startActivityForResult is deprecated, I go for the new way to handle activity results here. When you are creating intent to open Autocomplete activity, you should apply `setInitialQuery("Hawaii")` before building it. You can call the method from activity using LiveData. Here is the whole code inside my activity:

```
var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // There are no request codes
        val data: Intent? = result.data

        data?.let {
            val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data)
            makeToast(place.name.toString()) // <- Consume your result
        }
    }
}

private fun openSearchAutocomplete() {
    val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)

    val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
        AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields).setCountry("US") //United States
        .setInitialQuery("Hawaii") // <- set initial query here
        .build(this)
    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardView">
        <fragment  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            />
```

put this in your android xml code inside some layout like relative
  and then add fallowing java code by calling autocom() method in onCreate method and add Permission of location in Mainefest file

```
private void autocom()
{
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            LatLng string_location = place.getLatLng();
            String address = (String) place.getAddress();
            String name = (String) place.getName();
            // Log.i("LocationLatlang", String.valueOf(string_location));
            //Log.i("LocationAddress", address);
            //Log.i("Locationname", name);
            //Log.i("pppp", "Place: " + place.getName());

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i("ppperror", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: in build.gradle(module:app) add ->  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0' for cardView